# помогите исправить код c# windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Не могу сделать так, чтобы из второго класса запускались методы. не могу передать значения. В чем ошибка?

**Класс первый**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Numerics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form 
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        double a, b, c, x, x1, x2;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // посчитать
        {
           input();
           Equation equation = new Equation();
           equation.Equ(a, b, c);
           chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
           for (int i = -10; i < 10; i++)
           {
               chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, a * i * i + b * b * i + c);
           }
        }

        public void input()
        {
            a = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        }

        public void output(double x1, double x2)
        {
            textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(x1);
            textBox6.Text = Convert.ToString(x2);
        }

        public void outputD(double D)
        {
            textBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(D);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            for (int i = -10; i < 10; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, a * i * i + b * b * i + c);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox4.Clear();
            textBox5.Clear();
            textBox6.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

**КЛАСС ВТОРОЙ**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Equation 
    {       
        Double  x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        public void Equ(double a, double b, double c)
        {
            double D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
            form1.outputD(D);

            if (a == 0)
            {
                if (b == 0)
                {
                    form1.output(x1,x2);
                }
                else
                {
                    x1 = -c / b;
                    form1.output(x1, x2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (D < 0)
                {
                    Complex z1, z2;
                    z1 = new Complex(-b / 2 / a, Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(D)) / 2 / a);
                    z2 = new Complex(-b / 2 / a, -Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(D)) / 2 / a);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (D == 0)
                    {
                        x1 = -b / (2 * a);
                        form1.output(x1, x2);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
                        x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);

                        form1.output(x1, x2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что строкой кода

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

Вы пытаетесь получить доступ к графическому интерфейсу, т. е.  к главной форме вашего приложения. Однако эта строка кода создает новый объект Form1, а не подключает вас к вашей форме. Для доступа к форме пришлите ее объекту Equation в конструкторе. Как то так

```
  class Equation 
        {       
            Double  x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

            Form1 form1;

            public Equation(Form1 _form)
            {
               form1 = _form;
            }
         // Далее основной код
        }
```

Ну и при создании объекта  Equation надо писать следующее (если создаете его из формы, как у вас и есть)

```
Equation equation = new Equation(this);
```